# Java SimpleDateFormat for YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD

Tags: java, date

One of the external APIs we use requires

`"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD"`

format to be passed in

`XMLGregorianCalendar`

object. I am not sure if there is anything in Java that supports `"T"`. I was wondering, if a date can be parsed into above format in Java? An example of a valid date they have provided
is

`"2009-07-16T19:20:30-05:00"`............

```
 Update:

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ");        
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        String dateString = sdf.format(gc.getTime());       
        gc.setTime(sdf.parse(dateString));      
        XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
```

Output:

2014-04-17T13:11:30.000+01:00

Answer (score 25):

Use [JodaTime's](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) [`DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) API with `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"` date pattern

```
String date = "2009-07-16T19:20:30-05:00";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(date);
System.out.println(dateTime); // 2009-07-16T19:20:30-05:00
```

Comment: What if I have pattern like this "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" (T without single quotes), Is there any way around to parse this thing to Date object ?

Comment: @ShamimAhmad, it will throw an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'T'`.

Answer (score 8):

Try Java 8 [LocalDateTime.parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)

You could also use [threeten](http://www.threeten.org/) if you're on an earlier Java Version.

Example: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").format(yourLocalDateTime)`

Answer (score 7):

You need to put it in single quotes.

Try

```
YYYY-mm-dd'T'hh:MM:ssZ
```

Comment: Hi Pete, I tried it but somehow it appends "000". Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

Yes,you can.Try this date formatter.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```